# How to merge many documents, each containing several tex files?

Tags: combine

I'm writing a Lab manual with 13 Lab sessions, for each session, I provided a document containing 3 tex files, one for packages( say `packages.tex`, one for main file that the whole code is :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, margin=1in}


\input{packages}
\author{someone }


\begin{document}
    
    \maketitle
   
    \input{REPORT}

\end{document}
```

and the last one is `REPORT.tex` which contains the whole text for that specific lab session. Each 13 session, has these 3 files and I have a shared folder for the images used in all of these 13 sessions, now I want to merge all of the sessions into one project.
Is there any way to merge these 13 sessions without merging 3 tex files of each sessions into one tex file?

Edit: I want to be able to use `\tableofcontents` , etc.

Comment: It sort of depends on what goes into each file.  If every file has a document class and preamble, you will have to ignore them (standalone.sty does it, at least for standalone class).  If you don't care about hyperlinks or page numbers, pdfpages is the way to go.

Comment: As far I see,  you only need a main `main.tex` as the showed, but with the command `\title`  before  `\maketitle` and `\tableofcontents` after that, and finally  `\input{Report2}`, `\input{Report2} ... \input{Report12} `  after `\input{REPORT}`. Of course, the subtitles of each report should be a `\section` or `\part`. If each report already have a \maketitle and several sections, consider another class to use  `\chapter`  for titles of each report. If the default chapter style is a problem, with memoir and scrbook there are an option to show the chapters with a section-like style.